# Flutter Implementation of Isolates/compute inside stack of widgets - 'List<Future<Widget>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

The argument type 'List<Future>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

```
return SizedBox( width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height, child: Stack( alignment: Alignment.topLeft, children: listOfWidgets) );
```

listOfWidgets for example 10 widgets, each widget having one isolate and one compute which are running following function

```
String Calculate(int num){ int sum=num+num; return sum.toString(); }
```

Comment: can you include more sample data. the issue is you are getting future widget. Find more about [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the error speaks for itself, you don't have list of widgets, you have list of `Future`. you need to use `FutureBuilder` for each widget. `Stack` -> `FutureBuilder` -> `Widget`

Comment: @Hydra in each widget i am planing to use 10 isolates. how it is possible to use 10 isolates with one future builder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @RizwanAhmed no you need to use `FutureBuilder` for each item in your list, meaning you need to map your list to List of `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

> in each widget i am planing to use 10 isolates. how it is possible to
> use 10 isolates with one future builder?

you can try `Future.wait`

```
Future<String> foo;
Future<int> bar;
FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.wait([bar, foo]), // here your future function
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
    snapshot.data[0]; //bar
    snapshot.data[1]; //foo
  },
);
```

Comment: I follow your example but facing null value. AsyncSnapshot<List<double>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)                                                                                               FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait(
          [crossProduct, normalAngle, tangentAngle, normAndTangDiff]),
      // here your future function
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Stack(
  children: listOfWidgets.map(
    (future) => FutureBuilder<Widget>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Text('something went wrong');
        }
        return snapshot.data!;
      }
    ),
  ).toList()
),
```